# convert base 4 string to Decimal in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, integer, decimal, data-conversion

I have the following function that takes a string in the base of 4 and supposed to return a decimal integer, but my calculations seem to be off, so for "22" I need to get 10 but it's coming out as 5. Please help me fix this:

```
   base4Todec :: String -> Int
   base4Todec = foldr (\c s -> s * 4 + c) 0 . reverse . map c2i
       where c2i c = if c == '0' then 0 else 1
```

Note: I'm not allowed to use imports

Example: `base4Todec "22" = 10`

Comment: I'd use a different capitalization BTW, like `base4toDec`. also it's not a decimal integer, it's just integer.  :) of course after converting your base-4 string to an integer, it is easy to get its base-10 representation, by using `show` (or `print`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a function point-free is only good if it is clearer that way than the regular way. Here it doesn't look that way. So then,

```
base4Todec :: String -> Int
base4Todec cs  =  foldr (\c s -> s * 4 + c) 0 $ reverse $ map c2i cs
    where 
    c2i c  =  if c == '0' then 0 else 1
```

Not much change is it, but now the cause is clear:

```
    where 
    c2i c  =  if c == '0' then 0 else 1
```

Why `1`? `c2i '2' == 2` should hold, isn't it?

Your strings are not in binary. The maximum allowed digit for base 4 is *3*.

By the way the `foldr`, `reverse` and `map` can all be fused into one `foldl`. Which is better changed to `foldl'` here (as is nearly always).

Comment: there was no reason for foldr, reverse and map, how can I fuse them? also even after the change from 1 to 2, "33" converts to 10 instead of 15

Comment: change from 1 to 2? `c2i` should return `1` for `'1'`, `2` for `'2'`, `3` for `'3'` and `0` for `'0'`.

Comment: I'm new to haskell, how can I change my if to hold 1..3?

Comment: the simplest and easiest change is to continue the if, like so: `if ... then ... else if .... then .... else if ... then .... else ....` for as many cases as needed. in general this would not be written that way but with "guards" instead, but let's keep it for another time. smallest steps bring you the farthest. if there's no such saying, there should be. :)